# MariaDB cluster only sync empty database and tables but not the rows

Tags: mariadb, galera

I created a simple galera cluster with only two nodes. my problem is that I am able to create a database and table on one machine and see it on another but when I insert some data into that table I can not see that on the other machine. 
My Galera.cnf file is:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.0.101,192.168.0.100"

# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="192.168.0.101"
wsrep_node_name="db2"
```

the config on the other machine is:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.0.100,192.168.0.101"

# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="192.168.0.100"
wsrep_node_name="web2"
```

All the required ports are open and everything looks alright. when I check for the number of machine in the cluster it seems two machines are connected. what do you think can be the cause to this?

The Queries:

```
CREATE DATABASE playground;
CREATE TABLE playground.equipment ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, type VARCHAR(50), quant INT, color VARCHAR(25), PRIMARY KEY(id));
INSERT INTO playground.equipment (type, quant, color) VALUES ("slide", 2, "blue");
```

Here is the error code :
 [ERROR] Transaction not registered for MariaDB 2PC, but transaction is active

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` and one `INSERT`.

Comment: I added both of the queries I ran